# Print lists more pleasing to the eye in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def search(fru):
    myfile = open("sample.txt")
    fruit = myfile.read()
    fruit = fruit.splitlines() #Converts the contents of a file to a list
    if fru in fruit:
        val = "is there in the list",fru
        return val
    else:
        return "Not there in the list "

send = input("Enter fruit to search ")
result = search(send)
print(result)
if type(result) == list:
    for item in result:
        print(item)
```

The above is my code i intend to get an output like banana is in the list but the o/p am getting is ('banana' , 'is in the list') it is coming as a list

Comment: That is a mess, but you may want to try `pprint`.

Comment: im sorry if this is a mess i have just started to learn python and this was my first own program and im not still familiar with pprint the above method worked in a small dictionary app i made using a json file as reference

Comment: How will `type(result) == list` ever be true? Your function `search` only returns a string(`"Not there in the list "`) or a tuple (`"is there in the list",fru`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you want to replace this sample of code:

```
if fru in fruit:
    val = "is there in the list",fru
    return val
```

with:

```
if fru in fruit:
    val = "{} is there in the list".format(fru)
    return val
```